# Getting OkHttp to accept self-signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I successfully got the server to use a certificate in the form of a JKS file. HTTPS is working as expected when used with web browsers and other web clients.

For Android, my team uses the following to persuade OkHttp to accept the certificate.

```
static KeyStore readKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        // get user password and file input stream
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();

        java.io.InputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = ServiceProducer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/raw/keystore.jks");
            ks.load(fis, password);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {

        } finally
        {
            if (fis != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
            }

        }
        return ks;
    }
```

The code that uses the key:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new  OkHttpClient.Builder();
                KeyStore keyStore = readKeyStore();
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
                KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
                sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
                builder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("https://192.168.5.91:9443")
                        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client)
                        .build();
```

However, accessing the service throws the following exception:

`java.security.cert.CertPathValidationException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Have we done the certificate installation correctly? Or are we facing a different kind of problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this

Comment: I am also facing this issue.  Is there a good workaround?